# В основную форму не передается строка из второй формы C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть основная форма, есть форма для подключения к базе данных.
На форме подключения, я формирую строку подключения, которую хочу передать в основную форму, но после того, как форма подключения появляется по нажатию на кнопку, она отрабатывает, но строку не передает.
Вот тут я запускаю форму и хочу получить строку, которая была сформирована в методе `getConstring()`.

```
        private void toolStripButton_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectForm conForm = new ConnectForm();
        conForm.Show();
        constring = conForm.getConString();

    }
```

Вот код формы подключения:

```
 public partial class ConnectForm : Form
{

    public string server, port, userid, password, database;
    public bool isConnected = false;
    string constring;


    NpgsqlConnection connection;

    public ConnectForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox_Server.Text = "localhost";
        textBox_Port.Text = "5432";
        textBox_UserID.Text = "postgres";
        textBox_Database.Text = "AprioriData";
    }

    private void button_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public string getConString()
    {
        string constr = null;

        constr = "Server=" + server + "; Port=" + port + "; User Id=" + userid + "; Password=" + password + "; Database=" + database + ";";

        return constr;

    }

    private void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = textBox_Server.Text;
        port = textBox_Port.Text;
        userid = textBox_UserID.Text;
        password = textBox_Password.Text;
        database = textBox_Database.Text;

        constring = getConString();

        //constring = "Server=" + server + "; Port=" + port + "; User Id=" + userid + "; Password=" + password + "; Database=" + database+";";
        if (server == "" || port == "" || userid == "" || password == "" || database == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill in the fields!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                connection = new NpgsqlConnection(constring);
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect successfully!");
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Fail!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        this.Hide();

    }
}
```

Comment: `conForm.Show();` => `conForm.ShowDialog();`

Comment: `this.Hide();` => `this.Close();`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Это то, что надо!